How can I make the parameters of a uiState persist when turning the screen in Kotlin?
I've made a form in which I can create or edit cards. I'm using Kotlin + Jetpack Compose + Dagger Hilt + Room. It works OK, except for one thing. When I turn the screen without saving the record, I lose the modified data. Example: if I'm editing the card with title "X", and I change its title to "XYZ", and I turn the screen, the title goes back to "X".
I'm using sealed classes for the state.
This is the state of the screen:
@Parcelize
sealed class CardUiState: Parcelable {
    @Parcelize
    data object Loading: CardUiState()
    @Parcelize
    data class Creation(
        val titlePrefix: String = "",
        val title: String = "",
        val titleSuffix: String = "",
        val mainCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
        val selectedMainCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
        val timeCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
        val selectedTimeCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
        val error: Boolean = false,
        val errorMessageResId: Int? = null,
    ) : CardUiState()
    @Parcelize
    data class Edition(
        val card: Card,
        val titlePrefix: String = card.titlePrefix,
        val title: String = card.title,
        val titleSuffix: String = card.titleSuffix,
        val mainCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
        val selectedMainCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
        val timeCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
        val selectedTimeCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
        val error: Boolean = false,
        val errorMessageResId: Int? = null,
    ): CardUiState()
    @Parcelize
    data class Error(
        val message: String
    ): CardUiState()
}

This is the view model (it's much bigger but I'm only pasting the relevant code):
@HiltViewModel
class CardViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val cardRepository: CardRepository,
    private val categoryRepository: CategoryRepository,
    private val cardCategoryRelRepository: CardCategoryRelRepository,
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
): ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<CardUiState>(CardUiState.Loading)
    val uiState: StateFlow<CardUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        val savedState = savedStateHandle.get<CardUiState>("uiState")
        if (savedState != null) {
            _uiState.value = savedState
        }
    }

    private fun setState(uiState: CardUiState) {
        _uiState.value = uiState
        savedStateHandle["uiState"] = uiState
    }

    fun getCard(cardId: Int?) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                setState(CardUiState.Loading)
                val categories = categoryRepository.getCategories().first()
                if (cardId != null) {
                    val cardWithCategories = cardRepository.getCardWithCategories(cardId).first()
                    setState(CardUiState.Edition(
                        card = cardWithCategories.card,
                        selectedMainCategories = cardWithCategories.categories.filter { it.type == "main" },
                        mainCategories = categories.filter { it.type == "main" },
                        selectedTimeCategories = cardWithCategories.categories.filter { it.type == "time" },
                        timeCategories = categories.filter { it.type == "time" },
                    ))
                } else {
                    setState(CardUiState.Creation(
                        mainCategories = categories.filter { it.type == "main" },
                        timeCategories = categories.filter { it.type == "time" },
                    ))
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                setState(CardUiState.Error(
                    e.message ?: context.getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error)
                ))
            }
        }
    }
    
    fun onChangeTitle(title: String) {
        val currentState = _uiState.value
        if (currentState is CardUiState.Creation) {
            setState(currentState.copy(
                title = title,
                error = false,
                errorMessageResId = null,
            ))
        } else if (currentState is CardUiState.Edition) {
            setState(currentState.copy(
                title = title,
                error = false,
                errorMessageResId = null,
            ))
        }
    }
...

This is the screen (it's much bigger but I'm only pasting peaces of the relevant code):
@Composable
fun CardScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    titleResId: Int,
    viewModel: CardViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    canNavigateBack: Boolean = false,
    navigateUp: () -> Unit,
    cardId: Int? = null,
) {
    LaunchedEffect(cardId) {
        viewModel.getCard(cardId)
    }
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    CardScreenContent(
        modifier = modifier,
        titleResId = titleResId,
        uiState = uiState,
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
        canNavigateBack = canNavigateBack,
        navigateUp = navigateUp,
        onTitleChange = { viewModel.onChangeTitle(it) },
        onTitlePrefixChange = { viewModel.onChangeTitlePrefix(it) },
        onTitleSuffixChange = { viewModel.onChangeTitleSuffix(it) },
        onCategoryAdd = { category ->
            viewModel.addCategoryToSelection(category)
        },
        onCategoryRemove = { category ->
            viewModel.removeCategoryFromSelection(category)
        },
        onSave = {
            if (uiState is CardUiState.Creation) {
                val selectedCategories = (
                    uiState as CardUiState.Creation
                ).selectedMainCategories.plus((
                    uiState as CardUiState.Creation
                ).selectedTimeCategories)
                viewModel.save(
                    title = (uiState as CardUiState.Creation).title,
                    titlePrefix = (uiState as CardUiState.Creation).titlePrefix,
                    titleSuffix = (uiState as CardUiState.Creation).titleSuffix,
                    selectedCategories = selectedCategories,
                )
            } else if (uiState is CardUiState.Edition) {
                val selectedCategories = (
                    uiState as CardUiState.Edition
                    ).selectedMainCategories.plus((
                        uiState as CardUiState.Edition
                        ).selectedTimeCategories)
                viewModel.save(
                    title = (uiState as CardUiState.Edition).title,
                    titlePrefix = (uiState as CardUiState.Edition).titlePrefix,
                    titleSuffix = (uiState as CardUiState.Edition).titleSuffix,
                    selectedCategories = selectedCategories,
                )
            }
        },
    )
}

...
    when (uiState) {
        is CardUiState.Loading -> CircularProgressIndicator()
        is CardUiState.Error -> ErrorDialog(
            text = uiState.message,
            onDismiss = navigateUp
        )
        is CardUiState.Creation -> CardForm(
            title = uiState.title,
            titlePrefix = uiState.titlePrefix,
            titleSuffix = uiState.titleSuffix,
            mainCategories = uiState.mainCategories,
            selectedMainCategories = uiState.selectedMainCategories,
            timeCategories = uiState.timeCategories,
            selectedTimeCategories = uiState.selectedTimeCategories,
            onTitleChange = onTitleChange,
            onTitlePrefixChange = onTitlePrefixChange,
            onTitleSuffixChange = onTitleSuffixChange,
            onCategoryAdd = onCategoryAdd,
            onCategoryRemove = onCategoryRemove,
            error = uiState.error,
            errorMessageResId = uiState.errorMessageResId,
        )
        is CardUiState.Edition -> CardForm(
            title = uiState.title,
            titlePrefix = uiState.titlePrefix,
            titleSuffix = uiState.titleSuffix,
            mainCategories = uiState.mainCategories,
            selectedMainCategories = uiState.selectedMainCategories,
            timeCategories = uiState.timeCategories,
            selectedTimeCategories = uiState.selectedTimeCategories,
            onTitleChange = onTitleChange,
            onTitlePrefixChange = onTitlePrefixChange,
            onTitleSuffixChange = onTitleSuffixChange,
            onCategoryAdd = onCategoryAdd,
            onCategoryRemove = onCategoryRemove,
            error = uiState.error,
            errorMessageResId = uiState.errorMessageResId,
        )
    }

...
@Composable
fun CardForm(
    title: String = "",
    titlePrefix: String = "",
    titleSuffix: String = "",
    mainCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
    selectedMainCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
    timeCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
    selectedTimeCategories: List<Category> = emptyList(),
    onTitleChange: (String) -> Unit = {},
    onTitlePrefixChange: (String) -> Unit = {},
    onTitleSuffixChange: (String) -> Unit = {},
    onCategoryAdd: (Category) -> Unit = {},
    onCategoryRemove: (Category) -> Unit = {},
    error: Boolean = false,
    errorMessageResId: Int? = null,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = titlePrefix,
                onValueChange = onTitlePrefixChange,
                label = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.text_field_title_prefix)) },
                singleLine = true,
            )

...
EDIT
These are the elements of the NavHost which call the list of cards screen (Cards) and the card form to create/edit (CardDetail):
        composable(route = NavScreen.Cards.route) {
            CardsScreen(
                titleResId = NavScreen.Cards.titleResId,
                canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null,
                navigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() },
                onCardUpdateButtonClicked = { cardId ->
                    navController.navigate(
                        NavScreen.CardDetail.createRoute(cardId.toString())
                    )
                },
                onCardInsertButtonClicked = { navController.navigate(NavScreen.CardDetail.route) },
            )
        }
        composable(
            route = NavScreen.CardDetail.route,
            arguments = NavScreen.CardDetail.navArguments
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            val cardId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("cardId")
            CardScreen(
                titleResId = NavScreen.CardDetail.titleResId,
                canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null,
                navigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() },
                cardId = cardId?.toIntOrNull(),
            )
        }


Can you show what viewModel.getCard does? I don't see any problem in the code you posted...

@JanBína I've just added the viewModel.getCard() definition to the question.

yeah, that's where the problem is, when you rotate screen, the LaunchedEffect that calls viewModel.getCard runs again and reloads the state from repository, replacing the state you have saved in SavedStateHandle. Where do you get the cardId from? Can the cardId change, or will it stay the same for the lifetime of the viewModel? If it stays, you should do the loading in the viewmodel...

The cardId comes from the NavHost. In other view (with its own viewModel) I have the clasic LazyColumn with all the cards, each one can be edited by clicking on a edit button, and there is also a button for creating a card. If I click on create a card, cardId is null, if I do it on edit, cardId values the ID of the card I want to edit. So I guess cardId will stay the same for the lifetime of the viewModel. What do you mean with "doing the loading in the viewmodel"?

So, as we already established in the comments, the problem is calling viewModel.getCard from LaunchedEffect, which is invoked when you rotate screen and will reload card data from repository and replace the data you have in SavedStateHandle.
Since you use androidx navigation, you can get the navigation arguments from the SavedStateHandle inside of your viewmodel, see the documentation. Also note that you can conveniently getStateFlow directly from the SavedStateHandle, so you don't have to update two places separately. The resulting code can look like this:
class CardViewModel(
  private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {

  val uiState = savedStateHandle.getStateFlow<CardUiState>("uiState", CardUiState.Loading)

  init {
    if (uiState.value == CardUiState.Loading) {
      // CardUiState was not saved in savedStateHandle, you have to load data
      viewModelScope.launch {
        // get the id from you navigation arguments
        val cardId = savedStateHandle.toRoute<YourRoute>.cardId
        // load data from repository
        setState(getCard(cardId))
      }
    }
  }

  private suspend fun getCard(cardId: Int?): CardUiState {
    // ...
  }

  private fun setState(uiState: CardUiState) {
    savedStateHandle["uiState"] = uiState
  }

  // the rest stays the same:
  fun onChangeTitle(title: String) {
    val currentState = uiState.value
    val newState = ...
    setState(newState)
  }
}

From the compose code, you will just observe uiState and update data with methods like onChangeTitle. Loading data (getCard) is responsibility of ViewModel.

Thank you for answering, I've tried to change the code several times with no success. I don't understand very well some things, especially the line val cardId = savedStateHandle.toRoute<YourRoute>.cardId, I didn't know what to write there, so I've edited my question to include part of the current NavHost. Can you help me, please? With your comments, I understand that I have to remove the LaunchedEffect from the composable CardScreen, and pass the cardId to the CardViewModel instead of the CardScreen, Does this imply to generate the view model in the nav graph?

You should find that in the documentation I linked. But if you get the cardId like this now: backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("cardId"), you should be able to get it in viewModel like this: savedStateHandle.get<String>("cardId"). The toRoute is just a syntax sugar when you use typesafe arguments.

Ok, finally I understood it, and it worked! Thank you so much!

perfect, you're welcome!
